# ¿Bucle for asíncrono en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

Me encontré con un Bucle `for` con una sintaxis algo diferente, intente averiguar como funcionaba pero no lo logre, me daba error.

Me puse a investigar pero no encontré mucha información, según su sintaxis es un bucle `for` "asíncrono" o algo así, este seria el bucle `for` del que estoy hablando:

```
async for target in iter:
    block
```

Bueno mi pregunta es ¿Para que sirve este bucle `for`?, ¿Como funciona? y ¿En que circunstancias se debe de utilizar?

Me di cuenta también que no solo hay un bucle `for` con esa sintaxis diferente(`async`), hay funciones, `withs` y no se si hay mas.

```
async def funcname(parameter_list):
    pass

async with expr as var:
    block
```

Entonces ¿Porque `async` antes de declarar un bucle `for`, una función, etc?

---

*De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

El tema es muy complejo y extenso, pero voy a intentar dar una respuesta.

`async` es una keyword introducida junto a `await` en Python 3.5 y que permiten definir co-rutinas nativas.

Imaginemos que tenemos una aplicación que solicita datos de varios servidores diferentes,  la solicitud al servidor puede llevar un tiempo indeterminado en completarse. En condiciones normales el interprete ejecuta ciertas ordenes de forma secuencial esperando a que se complete la actual antes de pasar a la siguiente, en nuestro caso esto significaría esperar a que el servidor retorne antes de enviar la solicitud al siguiente, un tiempo de espera que es desperdiciado.

En lugar de esperar la respuesta, podríamos pasar a enviar la solicitud al siguiente servidor o procesar el retorno de otro mientras tanto y más tarde cuando retorne el anterior procesamos su retorno. De esta forma no tenemos el hilo sin hacer nada mientras una tarea I/O bloqueante retorna. Esta es la esencia un programa asíncrono.

Clásicamente se asocia asíncrono a  multiprocesamiento o multihilos. Simplificando mucho, cuando se tienen varios subprocesos en ejecución, cada núcleo de la CPU puede ejecutar un solo subproceso a la vez. Con el fin de permitir que todos los hilos/ procesos compartan recursos, la CPU realiza una operación que se llama cambio de contexto. Digamos que  en un intervalo aleatorio, guarda toda la información de contexto de un hilo y cambia a otro hilo, posteriormente carga el contexto y continua con el hilo anterior...

Los hilos y procesos tiene ciertos problemas, dos de ellos son que pueden ser pesados y costosos de desplegar y son susceptibles a sufrir condiciones de carrera, dado que de no sincronizar correctamente, el cambio de un hilo a otro no es algo determinado.

Una forma de hacer una **programación asíncrona sin recurrir a hilos o procesos es implementando un bucle de eventos**. Básicamente, tenemos una cola de eventos / trabajos y un bucle que simplemente extrae constantemente los trabajos de la cola y los ejecuta. Estos trabajos los vamos a llamar  co-rutinas, que serían un pequeño conjunto de instrucciones que pueden incluir también nuevos eventos que se deben volver a poner en la cola. En este caso tenemos **conmutadores de contexto controlados por la aplicación**, mientras espera a que alguna operación I/O bloqueante se complete, no hay cambios de contexto a nivel de CPU. **Todo se ejecuta en un mismo hilo**,  se ejecuta una única rutina a la vez y **se cambia de contexto solo en los puntos que se definen de forma explícita** (p.e `await`). Las co-rutinas permiten por tanto realizar operaciones multitarea cooperativa en la que cada co-rutina cede el control en puntos determinados y voluntariamente.

Unos cuantos conceptos clave son:

- **Corrutina (coroutine)**:  es una función especial que puede ceder el control a su interlocutor sin perder su estado. Esto nos suena, y mucho, a un generador, de hecho la co-rutinas se implementaron mediante generadores y el uso de `yield`/`yield from` inicialmente (co-rutinas basadas en generadores). En realidad una co-rutina es un consumidor, una extensión de una función generadora que puede generar valores y **aceptar valores externos**. La ventaja de usar una co-rutina es que podemos pausar la ejecución de una función y reanudarla más tarde dado que mantiene su contexto. Cuenta se llama a una co-rutina, en realidad no se ejecuta, sino que devolverá un objeto de rutina que puede ser pasado al bucle de eventos para ejecutarlo inmediatamente o más adelante.
- **Futuro (Future)**: es como un marcador de posición para un valor que se materializará en el futuro pero que ahora mismo no existe. Es similar a lo que en JS se conoce como promesas. Esta terminología quizás es más clara, es en esencia una promesa de que nos dará un valor de retorno cuando finalice la operación asíncrona, nos quedamos con este objeto futuro o promesa y cuando se cumpla podemos invocar un método para recuperar el resultado real.
- **Tareas (task):**  son planificadores para las co-rutinas, envolturas para las co-rutinas. Es una subclase de `Future`. Lo esencial es que permiten realizar un seguimiento de cuándo terminan el procesamiento, otras co-rutinas pueden esperar una tarea y también puede tomar el resultado de una tarea cuando haya terminado de procesarse. Las tareas se utilizan por tanto  para programar co-rutinas concurrentes.
- **Ciclo de eventos (event loop):** es el núcleo central  en `asyncio`. Nada de lo anterior tiene sentido sin él. Hay varias configuraciones y tipos de ciclos de eventos que se pueden usar dentro del módulo [**asyncio**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Una forma de proceder básica de ejemplo sería:

- Tenemos un ciclo de eventos se está ejecutando en un solo hilo
- El ciclo recibe tareas de la cola
- Cada tarea llama al siguiente paso de una coroutine.
- Si la co-rutina llama a otra co-rutina ( `await co-rutina_2`), la co-rutina actual se suspende y se produce un cambio de contexto. Se guarda el contexto de la co-rutina actual (variables, estado, ...) y se carga el contexto de la co-rutina llamada
- Si una co-rutina se encuentra con un código de bloqueo (I/O, sleep, etc), se suspende y el control se devuelve al ciclo de eventos.

En cuanto a tus tres ejemplos de uso de `async`:

- **`async def funcname()`**:

  Es la forma de [definir una co-rutina nativa desde Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines) (PEP 492), momento en el que se introdujeron las co-rutinas nativas, con `async`/`await`. Esto substituye al las co-rutinas basadas en generadores (`@asyncio.coroutine`, `yield from`, `yield`), los cuales serán eliminados en un futuro Python 3.10.

  ```
  import asyncio

  async def io_operation(ident):
      print(f'La operación {ident} ha comenzado')
      await asyncio.sleep(1) # Solo para emular una operación I/O bloqueante
      print(f'La operación {ident} ha terminado')

  async def main():
      await asyncio.gather(
          io_operation('A'),
          io_operation('B'),
          )

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Ciclo de eventos
      loop.run_until_complete(main())
  ```

  > La operación A ha comenzado
  >      La operación B ha comenzado
  >      La operación A ha terminado
  >      La operación B ha terminado

  Como ya se comentó, llamar a una co-rutina no ejecuta su contenido, igual que ocurre con un generador:

  ```
  >>> io_operation("A")
  <coroutine object io_operation at 0x7f13eac1fa48>)
  ```
- **`async with expr as var`**

  Es la [expresión para hacer uso del administrador de contexto asíncrono](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-for) de un objeto que lo implemente, es decir,  que puede  suspender la ejecución en sus métodos `__enter__` y `__exit__`.

  ```
  import asyncio

  class Foo:
      async def __aenter__(self):
          print("Entrando en el contexto")
          await asyncio.sleep(1)

      async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
          print("Saliendo del contexto")
          await asyncio.sleep(1)

  async def main():
      async with Foo() as foo:  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          print("Algo ocurre en medio...") 

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Ciclo de eventos
      loop.run_until_complete(main())
  ```

  > Entrando en el contexto
  >      Algo ocurre en medio…
  >      Saliendo del contexto
- **`async for target in iter`**

  Es la [expresión para iterar sobre un iterable asíncrono](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-async-with-statement) (puede llama código asíncrono en su método `__iter__` ) y sobre un iterador asíncrono  (puede llamar a código asíncrono en su método `__next__`₎.

  ```
  import asyncio

  class IterableAsincrono:
      def __init__(self, n):
          self._n = n

      def __aiter__(self):
          return self

      async def __anext__(self):
          item = await self.get_next()
          if item:
              return item
          else:
              raise StopAsyncIteration

      async def get_next(self):
          if self._n > 0:
              await asyncio.sleep(1)
              self._n -= 1
              return self._n

  async def main():
      async for item in IterableAsincrono(5):  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          print(item) 

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Ciclo de eventos
      loop.run_until_complete(main())
  ```

`async from` y `async with` solo pueden ser usados dentro del cuerpo de una co-rutina.

> No hay que intentar buscar sentido a los ejemplos, son muy simples y no representan usos reales.La única intención es mostrar el funcionamiento general y que sean ejecutables con el mínimo código.

Hay que dejar claro que las co-rutinas se ejecutan de forma concurrente, pero nunca en paralelo. En CPython los hilos tampoco pueden ejecutarse en paralelo por culpa del GIL, por lo que las co-rutinas son alternativas muy a tener en cuenta en muchos casos en los que podríamos usar hilos en situaciones dónde tenemos operaciones de entrada/salida bloqueantes (típicamente una solicitud de red). Proporcionan un nivel muy alto de concurrencia con muy poca sobrecarga y uso de memoria.