# prompt-toolkit como agregar diálogos cuando corre la aplicación en pantalla completa

Tags: python

Estoy trasteando con el prompt toolkit y me encuentro que al incluir los diálogos me da el error de que ya esta corriendo el event loop.

Lo que pretendo es presentar cuadros de dialogo y recibir la respuesta.
De momento le he puesto un keybinding de forma que para llamar al dialogo se pulsa la t (la función ask)

Pero como ya he mencionado, me da una excepción de que ya hay un evento loop corriendo.

He intentado poner el dialogo por si solo ya que yes_no_dialog crea una instancia de Application sin resultados y la documentación y ejemplos oficiales, no ayudan demasiado.
Estoy usando python 3.7 y la ultima versión de prompt-toolkit

El codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
"""
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from pygments.lexers.html import HtmlLexer

from prompt_toolkit.application import Application
from prompt_toolkit.application.current import get_app
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.bindings.focus import (
    focus_next,
    focus_previous,
)
from prompt_toolkit.layout.containers import Float, HSplit, VSplit, Window
from prompt_toolkit.layout.dimension import D
from prompt_toolkit.layout.layout import Layout
from prompt_toolkit.lexers import PygmentsLexer
from prompt_toolkit.buffer import Buffer
from prompt_toolkit.layout.controls import BufferControl, FormattedTextControl
from prompt_toolkit.layout.menus import CompletionsMenu
from prompt_toolkit.lexers import PygmentsLexer
from prompt_toolkit.styles import Style
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import yes_no_dialog
from prompt_toolkit.widgets import (
    Box,
    Button,
    Checkbox,
    Dialog,
    Frame,
    Label,
    MenuContainer,
    MenuItem,
    ProgressBar,
    RadioList,
    TextArea,
)

LIPSUM = ' '.join(("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Maecenas quis interdum enim. Nam viverra, mauris et blandit malesuada, ante est
bibendum mauris, ac digngtgtissim dui tellus quis ligula. Aenean condimentum leo at
dignissim placerat. In vel dictum ex, vulputate accumsan mi. Donec ut quam
placerat massa tempor elementum. Sed tristique mauris ac suscipit euismod. Ut
tempus vehicula augue non venenatis. Mauris aliquam velit turpis, nec congue
risus aliquam sit amet. Pellentesque blandit scelerisque felis, faucibus
consequat ante. Curabitur tempor tortor a imperdiet tincidunt. Nam sed justo
sit amet odio bibendum congue. Quisque varius ligula nec ligula gravida, sed
convallis augue faucibus. Nunc ornare pharetra bibendum. Praesent blandit ex
quis sodales maximus. """ * 100).split())

floats2 = Float(
            Frame(Window(FormattedTextControl(LIPSUM), width=80),
                  style='bg:#ff44ff #ffffff'),
            top=1,
    height=50)



def accept_yes():
    get_app().exit(result=True)


def accept_no():
    get_app().exit(result=False)


def do_exit():
    get_app().exit(result=False)


yes_button = Button(text='Yes', handler=accept_yes)
no_button = Button(text='No', handler=accept_no)
textfield  = TextArea(lexer=PygmentsLexer(HtmlLexer))
checkbox1 = Checkbox(text='Checkbox')
checkbox2 = Checkbox(text='Checkbox')

radios = RadioList(values=[
    ('Red', 'red'),
    ('Green', 'green'),
    ('Blue', 'blue'),
    ('Orange', 'orange'),
    ('Yellow', 'yellow'),
    ('Purple', 'Purple'),
    ('Brown', 'Brown'),
])

animal_completer = WordCompleter([
    'alligator', 'ant', 'ape', 'bat', 'bear', 'beaver', 'bee', 'bison',
    'butterfly', 'cat', 'chicken', 'crocodile', 'dinosaur', 'dog', 'dolphin',
    'dove', 'duck', 'eagle', 'elephant', 'fish', 'goat', 'gorilla', 'kangaroo',
    'leopard', 'lion', 'mouse', 'rabbit', 'rat', 'snake', 'spider', 'turkey',
    'turtle', ], ignore_case=True)

root_container = HSplit([
    VSplit([
        Frame(body=Label(text='Left frame\ncontent')),
        Dialog(title='The custom window',
               body=Label('hello\ntest')),
        textfield,
    ], height=D()),
    VSplit([
        Frame(body=ProgressBar(),
              title='Progress bar'),
        Frame(title='Checkbox list',
              body=HSplit([
                  checkbox1,
                  checkbox2,
              ])),
        Frame(title='Radio list', body=radios),
    ], padding=1),
    Box(
        body=VSplit([
            yes_button,
            no_button,
        ], align='CENTER', padding=3),
        style='class:button-bar',
        height=3,
    ),
])

root_container = MenuContainer(body=root_container, menu_items=[
    MenuItem('File', children=[
        MenuItem('New'),
        MenuItem('Open', children=[
            MenuItem('From file...'),
            MenuItem('From URL...'),
            MenuItem('Something else..', children=[
                MenuItem('A'),
                MenuItem('B'),
                MenuItem('C'),
                MenuItem('D'),
                MenuItem('E'),
            ]),
        ]),
        MenuItem('Save'),
        MenuItem('Save as...'),
        MenuItem('-', disabled=True),
        MenuItem('Exit', handler=do_exit),
        ]),
    MenuItem('Edit', children=[
        MenuItem('Undo'),
        MenuItem('Cut'),
        MenuItem('Copy'),
        MenuItem('Paste'),
        MenuItem('Delete'),
        MenuItem('-', disabled=True),
        MenuItem('Find'),
        MenuItem('Find next'),
        MenuItem('Replace'),
        MenuItem('Go To'),
        MenuItem('Select All'),
        MenuItem('Time/Date'),
    ]),
    MenuItem('View', children=[
        MenuItem('Status Bar'),
    ]),
    MenuItem('Info', children=[
        MenuItem('About'),
    ]),
], floats=[
    Float(xcursor=True,
          ycursor=True,
          content=CompletionsMenu(
              max_height=16,
              scroll_offset=1)),
])

# Global key bindings.
bindings = KeyBindings()
bindings.add('tab')(focus_next)
bindings.add('s-tab')(focus_previous)


style = Style.from_dict({
    'window.border': '#888888',
    'shadow': 'bg:#222222',

    'menu-bar': 'bg:#aaaaaa #888888',
    'menu-bar.selected-item': 'bg:#ffffff #000000',
    'menu': 'bg:#888888 #ffffff',
    'menu.border': '#aaaaaa',
    'window.border shadow': '#444444',

    'focused  button': 'bg:#880000 #ffffff noinherit',

    # Styling for Dialog widgets.

    'radiolist focused': 'noreverse',
    'radiolist focused radio.selected': 'reverse',

    'button-bar': 'bg:#aaaaff'
})

@bindings.add('c-c', eager=True)
@bindings.add('c-q', eager=True)
def _(event):
    """
    Pressing Ctrl-Q or Ctrl-C will exit the user interface.

    Setting a return value means: quit the event loop that drives the user
    interface and return this value from the `Application.run()` call.

    Note that Ctrl-Q does not work on all terminals. Sometimes it requires
    executing `stty -ixon`.
    """
    event.app.exit()

@bindings.add('w')
def mola(event):
    if not root_container.container.floats:
        root_container.container.floats = [floats2,]
    else:
        root_container.container.floats = []

@bindings.add('t')
def ask(event):
    result = yes_no_dialog(
        title='Yes/No dialog example',
        text='Do you want to confirm?').run()

application = Application(
    layout=Layout(
        root_container,
        focused_element=yes_button,
    ),
    key_bindings=bindings,
    style=style,
    mouse_support=True,
    full_screen=True)


def run():
    result = application.run()
    print('You said: %r' % result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero un descargo de responsabilidad :), no tengo experiencia alguna previa con prompt-toolkit y la respuesta es resultado de bucear un poco por el código fuente, por lo que puedes que existan mejores formas de hacer esto que no conozca. Realmente hay poca información fuera de la documentación, en el propio [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prompt-toolkit) hay ahora 20 preguntas con la etiqueta y poco más de la mitad con respuesta...

Dicho esto, lo que es seguro es que el error que tienes se debe a que al instanciar tu `yes_no_dialog` estás **generando una nueva aplicación**, la cual genera **su propio ciclo de eventos** (prompt-tolkit se implementa usando `asyncio` ([corrutinas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269596/bucle-for-as%C3%ADncrono-en-python/269657#269657)). Como no es posible tener dos ciclos de eventos al mismo tiempo tienes el error que muestras.

Tu diálogo tiene que formar parte de la aplicación y según veo esto no es posible con las implementaciones de diálogos de `prompt_toolkit.shortcuts`. Ahora bien, lo que puedes hacer es tener un `FloatContainer` en la raíz de tu aplicación (ya lo tienes en tu ejemplo) y simplemente añadir un nuevo objeto flotante construyendo tu propia versión de `yes_no_dialog` mediante `Dialog`:

```
def make_yes_no_dialog(yes_handler, no_handler):
    yes_btn = Button(text="YES", handler=yes_handler)
    no_btn = Button(text="NO", handler=no_handler)
    dialog = Dialog(
        title='Yes/No dialog example',
        body=Label(text='Do you want to confirm?', dont_extend_height=True),
        buttons=[yes_btn, no_btn],
        with_background=True
    )
    return dialog


def yes_handler():
    root_container.container.floats.remove(float_dialog)
    # Que quieres hacer cuando se pulsa YES

def no_handler():
    root_container.container.floats.remove(float_dialog)
    # Que quieres hacer cuando se pulsa NO

dialog = make_yes_no_dialog(yes_handler, no_handler)
float_dialog = Float(dialog)

@bindings.add('t')
def ask(event):
    if not float_dialog in root_container.container.floats:
        root_container.container.floats.append(float_dialog)
        event.app.layout.focus(dialog)
```

Se podría usar una clase para encapsular todo más, pero no quiero complicarlo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado, en realidad lo tenía casi pero me fallaba el presentar el dialogo, lo he logrado cambiando  la parte de "event.app.layout.focus(dialog)" por "get_app().layout.focus(dialog)" con lo que puede funcionar fuera de eventos de teclado